# Get Classes from File

Tags: java, compiler-construction, command-line, compilation, java-compiler-api

I have a sourcecode and in this `source` are two `classes` referenced.

Now I want to `compile` this code via `JavaCompiler` but therefore I have to first compile the two referenced `classes`.

Is there a better method than reading the file and search for the classes, to compile them first?

```
package data.testcases

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        XTest.class,
        YTest.class
})
public class ASuite {
}
```

XTest.java and YTest.java are in the same dir as Suite is

Comment: If its referencing other source(.java) files, they will be compiled automatically if you compile your code...

Comment: No they are not. The file to compile is a JUnit Suite and the classes are Testcases. The error when trying to compile the Suite is: java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol: class XTest
        XTest.class,

Comment: @Coretek So when you say 'no they are not' what you mean is 'yes they are'. Obviously the Java source refers to the class XTest. Otherwise you wouldn't be getting that compiler error.

Comment: @Coretek : Whats your package structure? Have you set your classpath?

Comment: I will add the source code to compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want to compile this code via JavaCompiler but therefore I have
>   to first compile the two referenced classes

No you don't. As long as the Java compiler can find those classes it will compile them automatically. That means that they need to be located in the same directory system as the file you are actually compiling, or else locatable via the -sourcepath option.

Comment: I'll have a look into the sourcepath option thanks for that in first instance.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs. for [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) suggests to me that adding them to the iterable collection of `compilationUnits` provided to [`getTask(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html#getTask%28java.io.Writer,%20javax.tools.JavaFileManager,%20javax.tools.DiagnosticListener,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) should achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is definitiveliy a better method. Use a build tool like [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to organize your builds. There are several [tutorials](http://wiki.apache.org/ant/AntTutorials) included in the Ant Wiki.

Comment: No I don't want to use external tools.